# Install Debian kerner 5.14

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I just got a laptop with a wireless adapter (MEDIATEK 7961) supported only by kernel 5.14+

I installed the latest kernel (5.15.0-2) from the unstable Debian repository but I can't get it working. I would like to try an older version, like 5.14.

I got 5.15.0-2 simply pointing to unstable Debian repo and upgraded the system

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
```

Is there a way to specify which kernel version I want to install, or any other way to install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately pointing `apt` to `unstable` and upgrading the system, unless you did an `apt full-upgrade`, has probably left you with a mix of `unstable` and whatever you had before running the upgrade. There are no guarantees at all that such a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) mix will actually work.

If you only recently got the laptop, reinstalling might be the easiest and quickest way back to a stable configuration.

The easiest way to get a newer kernel to a stable version of Debian is to use the [backports repository](https://backports.debian.org/) designated for that release.

For example, [the backports repository for Debian 11 (`bullseye`)](https://backports.debian.org/changes/bullseye-backports.html) currently has kernel version 5.14.9-2~bpo11+1 available. (The `~bpo11` part of the version number indicates it's from the backports repository for Debian 11.)

To get a 5.14 kernel for Debian 11 from the backports repository, you should:

1. add `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or create a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list` for it, and add it there)
2. run `apt update` to download the package index from the newly-added backports repository
3. run `apt install linux-image-amd64/bullseye-backports` to install the kernel package from the backports repository (currently version 5.14.9+2~bpo11+1)

The distribution's normal packages will be used by default by `apt`. Whenever you want to install a newer version from the backports repository, you will have to explicitly specify that you want the version from the `bullseye-backports`. If the backports package you already have installed gets updated in the backports repository, `apt` should handle updates for it just as usual. But it won't automatically add more packages from the backports repository without your explicit request.

Comment: thanks for that. I did exactly what you suggested and I got a 5.14 kernel version, not the one you mentioned tough. It installed 5.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64. Unfortunatelly I'm still facing issues to boot the system. I will raise another question to this problem later.

Comment: just in case .. this is the issue I started to see after upgrading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683072/debian-text-mode-framebuffer-issue-kernel-5-14