# Debian text mode framebuffer issue - Kernel 5.14

Tags: debian, framebuffer, backports

I can't fix the startup issue I'm facing since I updated my Debian (bullseye) to backports distribution in order to get the **Kernel 5.14**

[image]

As per my researching it seems to be something related to the framebuffer and nvidia adapters (GeForce RTX 3050 in my case)

I tried the steps described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86561/how-can-i-increase-the-console-resolution-of-my-ubuntu-server) other post with no success.

Here are few information about my hardware and configuration that might help someone to understand what might be wrong.

```
$ ls -la /boot/
total 128344
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Dec 18 09:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root     4096 Dec 18 08:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   236055 Sep 30 15:36 config-5.10.0-9-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   243590 Oct 10 07:33 config-5.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 Dec 19 07:47 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 41722190 Dec 16 17:03 initrd.img-5.10.0-9-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 75123714 Dec 18 09:57 initrd.img-5.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       83 Sep 30 15:36 System.map-5.10.0-9-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       83 Oct 10 07:33 System.map-5.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6833568 Sep 30 15:36 vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7225472 Oct 10 07:33 vmlinuz-5.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux>Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-9-amd64"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="15"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=791"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="1280x1024x16"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
```

```
$ lspci -v | egrep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25e2 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Comment: Please try installing binary NVIDIA drivers (and disabling `nouveau` in the process): https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers